# Bootstrap grid framwork does not work with form-control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I am using `Bootstrap`s grid system to make my `input` box smaller. However, it seems to conflict with `form-control`.

HTML:

```
<form class="col-md-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="input_box" class="form-control col-md-3"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

In Chrome's developer tools, the `25%` (for `.col-md-3` is automatically crossed out). If I take out `.form-control` then it works but looks ugly.

How do I use them both? Note that I do not want to change the width in .formcontrol because I have other forms that also use this and will get messed up

[image]

Comment: Try using a div around the input with the `col-md-*` as recommended in [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Comment: Are you saying for each input box I should wrap a div around it

Comment: Yeah, did you read the docs? The input is contained in `<div class="col-sm-*">`

Comment: I was wondering if there could be a better option than having a ton of divs, looks really messy when developing

Comment: Looks like **Skelly** wanted you to do what he/she likes @OneMoreQuestion. He/She's not happy with you get what you liked

Comment: It's not about being "happy". It's about the recommended approach in the official docs. ;-)

Comment: Thanks folks, I appreciate all the help. I guess wrapping every single input in a separate div is the only approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
<form>
   <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="input_box" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The `col-md-3` should be it's own DIV since `form-group` [behaves like a Bootstrap `row`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

Comment: Yes but without seeing OP's whole HTML I couldn't do it. He/She was using `col-md-8` in the form tag thus I couldnt get the clear idea. So I was sticking to his/her requirement for the moment